# Increasing speed of blob insert to oracle table

Tags: java, oracle

I am working on a java application that reads files from a cd and uploads each file as a blob to an oracle table. The application runs quite slow, only inserting  10-20 files per second. I am looking for a way to speed up this rate of inserting.

Comment: did you do it locally or thru internet?

Comment: Have you done any timing to see if the bottleneck is reading or writing?

Comment: Related to what @Jegg said - is the DB local or external?

Answer (score 2):

The first step of such an exercise is to identify *why* it is slow, or to put it another way, you need to find the bottleneck before you can improve anything. There are several things that could be causing a bottleneck in your application:

1. Reading from the CD. If this is the bottleneck, the only way I know of to speed this up is to buy a new CD drive.
2. Your java application. If this is the bottleneck, you could speed it up by using multiple threads to insert the items into the database.
3. The Oracle Database. I doubt that this is the bottleneck, and if it is I wouldn't be able to say how to speed it up.

In order to find the bottleneck, you should eliminate the possibilities one by one:

1. Eliminate the CD drive by pre-loading all (or as many as you can to get a good idea of the speed) into memory in your app before you start your timer (I assume you have a way of timing this as you mention a rate in the question). If it is still slow, then the CD player is not the issue.
2. I wouldn't bother trying to eliminate the Oracle database as the cause - I would assume it is the Java application at this point and crank up the number of threads doing the work until the database falls over. You will probably find this speeds things up.

If neither of these things help, then it sounds like you might have the wrong database for the job. Oracle is a highly efficient enterprise grade piece of kit and if it isn't performing as fast as you expect then it's probably mis-configured or the files are larger than Oracle is designed for.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, the bottleneck could also be network latency or network throughput when contacting the database. If latency is the problem, using multiple threads should also help. If throughput is the problem, you need a faster network connection to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have compared reading the files from my computer and writing them to Oracle against reading them from the cd and confirmed that reading from the cd does cause some delay. Using a faster cd reader will hopefully speed things up.

Comment: As for the actual reading and writing to the database, I have tried using a thread pool to simultaneously read and write many files at once and this surprisingly took longer than simply reading and writing the files one by one the order they are stored in an array list obtained from the cd being used.

Comment: My reading/writing process is the following:
1. Connect to the database and create a prepared statement object using a string containing the SQL command I am using to insert each BLOB
2. Use an enhanced for loop to iterate through each filename string in the array list.
3. Run a separate method that creates a file object using the current filename string
4. Create a FileInputStream object from the new file
5. set the FileInputStream as the prepared statement's binary stream

Comment: 6. Execute the prepared statement
7. Close the FileInputStream

This process happens for each file on the cd. Are there any quicker/more efficient ways of inserting each file to the database?

Comment: There could be a quicker way. Your current way is very MEMORY efficient, but you want it to be fast, so let's use more memory. Currently you are performing steps 1 to 7 for a single file, waiting for all steps complete before starting the next file. However, you should not wait until a file is inserted into the database before you start loading the next file from the CD. To do this, have a single thread load all the files (not a FileInputStream, you need to load the actual file as a String or something) and load them onto a queue. IN PARALLEL, have MULTIPLE threads taking files off the queue

Comment: and insert them into the database.

Comment: Essentially what I'm saying is that at all times you should have some code reading from the CD drive. Currently you are doing things like connecting to the database and making network calls while the CD drive is inactive. The CD drive should be active all the time, loading the files into memory. The piece of code loading the files from memory into the database can work alongside that.